# Random failure in TCL package initialization procedure

Tags: tcl

I am converting big project from 8.4 to 8.6. There is a shared library which provides TCL package. The init proc of package is crashing randomely in 8.6 and it's structure looks strange for me. Here is the content of init proc

```
  Tcl_ResetResult(interp);
  Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "package_name", "1.0");
  // Register new Tcl commands

  // Then goes other package initialization which linked to this .so statically
  otherlib_Init(interp);
  Tcl_StaticPackage(interp, "otherlib", otherlib_Init, otherlib_Init);
```

Tcl_PkgProvide line and other lib initialization looks strange for me but I am not sure. Commenting and uncommenting lines in this function sometime fixes the problem but since failure is random I am not sure which part is not correct.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Why do you think it's the initialization code which causes the problem? It indeed might be an *indirect* cause while the real, root cause is somewhere else. I'd try running your code under `valgrind` to try to catch memory mismanagement problems.

Comment: It's probably an extremely good idea to check for error codes from those functions that can produce them…